# Data structure to capture Rails (or in general, in UML) models associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tree, uml

I am trying to come up with a convenient data structure that would allow me to capture all associations among my Rails models (I already got all associations using some metaprogramming). Any ideas? The closest I got is a tree with the root node being a special node called `root`, and then the first children are models with no parent models (that is, not `belong_to`), and the second level down is the rest.

The reason I want this is that I want to process the models in the following fashion:

1. Start with models with no parent models, that is ones that have no `belong_to` association to another model.
2. Move to those that have `belong_to` dependence on models from 1.
3. Deal with nesting, so if C belongs to B belongs to A, I want to process A first, then B, then C.

A breadth first traversal comes to mind, but I can't quite get the data
structure to reflect this. Perhaps I am looking for a better data structure.

Comment: What is `belong_to`? A stereotype? How would you model a `model`? As component? I do not see the UML part in your question.

Comment: `belong_to` has a specific meaning in Rails, but in UML it's a simple 1 to n association, so A belongs to B means B can have n As. The `model` could be anything, but let's say a Ruby object. I just want to pick the correct data structure that would allow me to express relationships among my database backed models.

Comment: It's a moment ago since I touched Rails, but are you focusing on the data model inside?

Comment: Yes, I use some metaprogramming to get something like `Hash[modelA] = [modelB, modelC]` where the array is a list of associations for modelA. I am merely interested in  a data structure that will let me efficiently process the models according to the rules I specified above in my question.

Comment: I did something like that using Enterprise Architect. I'll dig and see what has been left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure I am looking for is a directed acyclic graph.

Comment: So I guess you're happy with that? I could not find my models. Probably I dropped it for some "too busy" reason ;-)

Comment: Yes, I think I got it. Thanks for your help Thomas.